# Maximum size for AppBundle for Playstore

Tags: android

I have bundle size 148mb but when i upload on playstore it becomes 109mb. So can i upload appbundle size of atleast 170mb..? Because after all download size will be less than 150mb. Please explain.

[image]

Comment: please share the image APK analyze.

Comment: APK analyzer showing the same download size, but on playstore it is reduced